# Need method to delete dependencies using console application

Tags: dynamics-crm

I had error to delete dependencies of attribute. First of all I have retrieved all dependencies using  **RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteRequest**

```
RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteRequest dependencyRequest = new RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteRequest
        {
            ComponentType = componentType,
            ObjectId = retrieveResponse.AttributeMetadata.MetadataId.Value,
        };
```

and program retrieves every dependence correctly.
Then I would like to delete them using

```
 foreach (var component in dependencyResponse.EntityCollection.Entities)
        {
            DeleteRequest deleteRequest = new DeleteRequest
            {
                Target = new EntityReference(component.LogicalName, component.Id)
            };
            service.Execute(deleteRequest);
```

But program gave me error **The 'Delete' method does not support entities of type 'dependency'. MessageProcessorCache returned MessageProcessor.Empty. '**. Maybe I did it with wrong method. I would like to ask if there is method to delete dependencies not records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the dependency can be of different types, for example the attribute can be inside a form, inside a view, as a part of another calculated attribute.

The `RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteRequest` will help you to find the Dependencies but you can't delete them with a single call, based on the dependency type you will need to perform a specific action (editing the form or the view following my previous example)

Comment: Could you pass me the link of your previous example?

Comment: the "previous example" I mentioned is in the first phrase: "for example the attribute can be inside a form, inside a view, as a part of another calculated attribute"

Comment: Sorry, but is there any way to delete dependencies programmatically?

Comment: each dependency type can be deleted by code but how it's done can be different (for example removing a field from the form requires to edit the xml and upload the new version, making sure the xml is still correct)